# When I just view the screen time settings in MacOS it changes iOS screen time settings

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, screen-time

We have screen time settings for our girls and we have had various issues over the years but have been able to work through most of them. We recently discovered a pattern that we need some insight on.

When we open screen time settings on our laptop, not changing anything, just simply view the settings, the settings on the phone are reset to be more restrictive. Additionally macOS doesn't allow us to change the settings.

The solution we have found is to simply open the settings and on our phone. Much like in macOS, we merely opened the settings on our phone and they fixed on our daughter's phone.

Thoughts?